# Как можно переместить toolbar в окне?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Хочу переместить toolbar вертикально слева как это можно реализовать в данном классе?
Пример класса интерфейса

```
class RedactorUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.chosen_points = []
        self.design_ui()
        self._image = QPixmap('workspace.png')
        self.setGeometry(0, 30, self._image.width(), self._image.height())
        self.setWindowTitle('RedactorUI')
        self.dictOfFlags = {'pen': False}

    def design_ui(self):
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Panel of instruments')
        self.toolbar.orientation()
        penAction = QAction(QIcon('pen.png'), '&Pen', self)
        brushAction = QAction(QIcon('brush.png'), '&Brush', self)
        rectangleAction = QAction(QIcon('rectangle.png'), '&Rectangle', self)
        ellipseAction = QAction(QIcon('ellipse.png'), '&Ellipse', self)
        eraserAction = QAction(QIcon('eraser.png'), '&Eraser', self)
        anotherBrushAction = QAction(QIcon('anotherBrush.png'), '&AnotherBrush', self)
        self.toolbar.addAction(penAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(brushAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(rectangleAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(ellipseAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(eraserAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(anotherBrushAction)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У метода [addToolBar](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qmainwindow.html#addToolBar) есть возможность указывания [ToolBarArea](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qt.html#ToolBarArea-enum):

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('ToolBarArea')

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Panel2')
        self.toolbar.addAction('1')
        self.toolbar.addAction('2')
        self.toolbar.addAction('3')

        self.toolbar2 = self.addToolBar('Panel1')
        self.addToolBar(Qt.Qt.LeftToolBarArea, self.toolbar2)
        self.toolbar2.addAction('a')
        self.toolbar2.addAction('b')
        self.toolbar2.addAction('c')

        self.toolbar3 = Qt.QToolBar('Panel3')
        self.addToolBar(Qt.Qt.RightToolBarArea, self.toolbar3)
        self.toolbar3.addAction('x')
        self.toolbar3.addAction('y')
        self.toolbar3.addAction('z')

        self.toolbar4 = Qt.QToolBar('Panel4')
        self.addToolBar(Qt.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, self.toolbar4)
        self.toolbar4.addAction('+')
        self.toolbar4.addAction('-')
        self.toolbar4.addAction('=')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

[Скриншот](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/0766f441f751ec9b6dff9e1ab2cae45ff01415fc/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/ToolBarArea):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, делал через toolbar.orientation в итоге полоса toolbar'a была по середине экрана